# How to open a new content in a form without opening a new form?

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I make a full-window content to appear/change in a form on a press of a button?

Like, I have a menu, and when I press a "new file" in it it opens a new editable file in the same -already open- window.

I've saw people told to use TabControl and GroupBox for it (and to HIDE unused content) but I have hard time believing it: it would mean that all the windows are open automatically as soon as programm is opened. But what if I have a hundreds of possible windows!? It would be a very slow program. Is there no way to really open only that part of content that is needed right now and not *hide* (make "invisible") the rest?

Comment: Not very clear what the issue is.  Post the code that is causing you problems.

Comment: Totally agree with @LarsTech unclear what the issue is.. Best guess now is MDI Forms, but post code or screenshots or mock-ups.

Comment: Why would that mean all the windows are opened automatically? That would be controlled by the code. And if you have hundreds of windows, the program will likely run slowly. What do you mean by "open only that part of content that is needed"? What content are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way is to use the visual studio designer to design your form and add the items that you want to be shown whenever the button is clicked. Make all these items invisible by setting property Visible to false.

```
// these existing controls should be made visible when button is clicked
private IEnumerable<Control> myBusyControls = new List
{
    this.ProgressBar1,   // shows Progress
    this.BusyImage,      // shows that I am busy
    ...
}

private void ShowBusy(bool busy)
{
    foreach (var control in myBusyControls)
    {
        control.Enabled = busy;
    }
}

private void OnButtonStartProcess(object send, EventArgs e)
{
     // disable sender, so the process can't be started twice
     ((Control)sender).Enabled = false;
     this.ShowBusy(true);
     this.StartProcess();   
}

// this will be called when the process is finished:
private void OnProcessFinished()
{
     this.ShowBusy(false);
     this.buttonStartProcess.Enabled = true;
}
```